# MySQL Update Field With JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, json

How do i update and copy data from the same table but the new data is JSON formatted data.

I am expecting the updated field to be: **{"t":"token1", "s":"secret1"}**

DB user_api table:

```
(id) (token) (secret) (api)
---------------------------
 1   token1  secret1  NULL
```

Update query:

```
UPDATE user_api SET api = '{"t":"' +token+ '", "s":"' +secret+ '"}';
```

Comment: sidenote: you realize that without a WHERE clause, it will update your entire table. Not a problem if you only have or will always have the one row.

Comment: MySQL treats `+` as an addition operator; but has a [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function that allows you to concatenate strings

Comment: **From a database design prespective:** It does not make much sense to concatenate 2 columns into a third column. If some part of your App needs this done, then do it in the PHP when you present or make some use of this concatenation.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the input. This is only to update existing records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CONCAT`

```
UPDATE user_api SET api = CONCAT('{"t":"', token, '", "s":"', secret, '"}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON_SET()` function instead.

```
UPDATE `user_api` SET `api` = JSON_SET(`api`,'$.t',token,'$.s',secret) WHERE ...
```

This helps you to get rid of all the `CONCAT` stuff. JSON_SET() function insert the key/value pair if the key is not exists in the specified field. If it exists, then the function update the value.

You can use `JSON_INSERT()` function if you want to insert if the key doesn't exists. Or you can use `JSON_REPLACE()` function if you want just update the value if the key exists.